# Error configuration for nginx-ingress controller

Tags: reactjs, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a react app that is first built and then served using nginx inside the docker container.

The container is running in k8s cluster which is exposed using nginx-ingress controller.

Now I want to setup the ssl certificate for the app, I have already bought ssl certs.

how do I configure it? anyone help me!

I was thinking to enable sal both in nginx inside docker and ingress-controller but that didn't worked. why

This is my nginx-ingress file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: devil
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.example.com
    secretName: devil-tls
  rules:
  - host: dev.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: devil-web-service
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: api-example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: devil-api-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

This config is not running the app in https mode. Is it the port 80 that's affecting it?

Comment: If you're using `kubernetes/ingress-nginx`, [have you followed the tutorial](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/)?

Comment: yes everything, created secrets added to ingress. The only problem here is I have 2 nginx one with ingress and the other one is inside the docker container which serves the react build scripts

Comment: The one inside the container shouldn't use TLS at all.

Comment: you are saying that the one inside should be serving through port 80

Comment: The port doesn't matter, but it shouldn't use TLS, because any traffic to it would be from the ingress Nginx only (where it will get configured as a backend).

Comment: I have removed the ssl/tls from the nginx.conf file inside the docker container nginx. Still the issue persists...i think the nginx should listen to port 443 this is where the https serves...

Comment: No, the server within the container doesn't need to care about TLS if there's the Nginx ingress in front of it. What is "the issue" that persists?

Comment: the issue is that https is not working

Comment: What does that mean? You will need to show us (by editing your question, not here in the comments) the steps you have taken to configure HTTPS for your ingress, and the symptoms of it not working.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that!